bound for SR1 update
Suppose the exact hessian $H^\star$ as function of vector x (no need to further be specified) and the initial SR-1 approximation $H$ are globally bounded in some norm of your choice by some real finite constant M, i.e. $\|H^\star(x)\|\leq M \ \forall x$ and $\|H\|\leq M$. For a fixed arbitrary long given arbitrary sequence of pairs of vectors $x,s$ of not-your-choice with which exact gradient tangents $y=H^\star(x) \cdot s$ are computed, the updates read:
$$ H := H + \frac{v \cdot v'}{v' \cdot s}$$
where $v=y-H \cdot s$. Also, updates are skipped when $|v' \cdot s|<\tau \cdot \|v\| \cdot \|s\|$ in some norm of your choice and some tolerance $\tau>0$.
Question/Task: Bound the norm of $\|H\|$ at each moment. Conjecture: $\|H\|\leq const \cdot M$.
I need to know whether such bound in fact exists and what the constant is. Since my matrix dimension is large, it would be unpleasant if the constant depended heavily on n. Naturally however, in some matrix norms a dependence on n seems unavoidable, thus 2-norm and frob-norm are probably most attractive.
Many thanks for any help or pointers to actually useful literature on that regard.
